# Tomcat webapp symbolic link

Tags: tomcat, symlink

I have a tomcat application and I have a folder inside webapps which is massive.
ex : c:/tomcat/test-app/webapps/images.

The images folder is a huge one.  I would like to move the image to a different drive , without changing the code.

Is that possible with symbolic links?  BTW I am using Windows..

Thanks,
MJ

Answer (score 0):

Back in the time when I used Windows, it didn't know about symbolic links, but I hear that some things change over time. Did you already try it?

The one drawback that you'll have to live with if you have this folder separate of your application, but still fully embedded within it: Tomcat might delete the folder when you undeploy the application, and surely won't create a link on redeployment.

And if you plan to upload into this directory at runtime (as so many questions on stackoverflow indicate), plan for data loss for the same reason. You'll also be subject to people uploading and executing JSPs- read: Remote Code Execution, on your server. If you intend to upload: Don't, rather upload elsewhere and provide a DownloadServlet or similar. Then there's also no more need for a symlink, as the DownloadServlet can just access that directory transparently.